# Within gulpfile, pass JSON object to task

Tags: javascript, gulp

In the code below, my `make` task calls a javascript function `buildTemplate` which I pass a JSON object to. Ideally, however, I'd like to replace this function with a `build-template` task which I pass the object to instead. Is this possible? Also, is adding javascript functions to supplement a gulpfile like I'm doing considered bad practice?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Include Plugins
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var templates = require('./config/templates.json');

// Watch Files for Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./input/structure/*/*.liquid', ['make']);
});

gulp.task('make', function() {
  // get a list of all templates (pull from config file)
  for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    var template = templates[i];
    buildTemplate(template);
  };
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', [
  'make',
  'watch'
]);

// Helper Function
function buildTemplate(template) {
  var template_title = template['title'];
  gulp.src(
    [
      './input/structure/snippets/header.liquid',
      './input/structure/templates/' + template_title + '.liquid',
      './input/structure/snippets/footer.liquid'
    ])
    .pipe(concat(template_title + '.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./output/')
  );
};
```

Comment: Well, you can use `gulp.run` for that kind of stuff, but I don't really see why. Can you describe a use-case?

Comment: You shouldn't use `gulp.run`. However,  if you need, you can create a `buildTemplate` task that depends on `make` task, and that `make` task modifying the global variable `templates`, which can be used in `buildTemplate` task. Also, `gulp` file is actually a js file and use of functions is encouraged.

Comment: Well, I'd like one master `build-template` task that I can pass different template objects to. Depending on which template object is passed, different files will be globbed, and hopefully I'll be able to insert different property values into my HTML the object.

Comment: @Jashwant - any chance you could provide a code example of this?

Comment: Why `make` is a task ? Shouldn't it ( the loop ) be a part of `buildTemplate` task ? It is synchronous after all. Are you expecting something else in `make` ?